# Query with 2 selected columns returns only 1 column per row

Tags: php, mysql

I am running the following query.

I expect to get both `user.name` and `activities.name` for every row in my result, but I only seem to get `activities.name`.

Why am I not seeing the names of each user that did the actual activity?

```sql
SELECT user.name, activities.name 
    FROM user_activities 
    LEFT JOIN user ON user.userid = user_activities.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.activityid = user_activities.activity_id
```

Ouput:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bought a House.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Purchased a game.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Purchased a game.
        )

)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since they share the column name, try to add an alias for that column:

```
SELECT user.name AS user_name , activities.name AS activity_name
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong to understand your question you might need to use alias to identify names of a user that'll result into non-ambiguous fields. Just Update your query like as below it'll result as you desired

```
SELECT u.name as user_name, a.name as activites_name FROM user_activities ua LEFT JOIN user u ON
    u.userid = ua.user_id LEFT JOIN activities a ON a.activityid
    = ua.activity_id
```